# Wordpress <?php body_class(); ?> issue

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

I built my theme into WordPress and all was good, then I wanted to add woocommerce to the theme to add a shop. The woocommerce was not showing its styles. So I did some research and found the reason was my  `<body>` tag should of been `<body <?php body_class(); ?>>`.

This was not in the guide I followed to convert the html.

So I added the tag in and the woocommerce styling appears fine. BUT the whole site has pushed left.

Here is the site - www.theinurse.com could anyone let me know why? I have tried a few things in css but nothing has resolved it. If i edit the following css the site moves

```
html, body {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0pt;
    }
```

If I edit margin it moves, but if I set `margin-left: auto; margin-right:auto;` etc etc it does nothing. But if I do `margin-left:100px;` it moves the site right 100px.

Baffling me! If I remove the body_class tag it sits perfectly. Please help me.

Comment: I'm having trouble getting your web address to resolve?  Are you sure the web address you typed is correct?

Comment: hi josh, http://www.theinurse.com should be correct?

Comment: Strange when I click that link its not resolving for me either but if i type it into the browser it works fine

Comment: Excellent, just checked on 2 other computers and neither are resolving, perfect time for the host to have issues.

Comment: If you're a long-time reader, you should know better than to try to offer money for a solution. That isn't how this site works.

Comment: Just want the issue resolved, obviously i would rather not pay.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try to replace this:

```
<?php body_class(); ?>
```

by this:

```
<body <?php body_class(); ?>>
```

?

Comment: Sorry, thats what it is <body <?php body_class(); ?>> I should have been more clear

Comment: And did you try with a simple `padding: 0px`?

Comment: Or maybe `float: left`? I'm sorry, I don't see the problem so I scan all possibilities to fix it...

Comment: Yeh understood mate, that didnt work either. The site was positioned perfectly before changing the <body> tag, so its something either clashing in the body_class or im missing something in my theme. But being new to WP I am lost where to look, google is not helping on this issue either.

Comment: Last chance... try to not apply your css to `html, body` but to `.Frame`, .Frame is a class I saw in the code of your page.

Answer (score 0):

If you have declared

```
add_theme_support( 'woocommerce' );
```

the system expect you to have the WooCommerce styles integrated in your theme stylesheet. This is why it don't call for the default stylesheet.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot the re-add the body class `Frame`. Your CSS code uses the Frame class to center the content.

```
<body <?php body_class('Frame'); ?>>
```

The `Codex` entry for [body_class()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/body_class) states there is a parameter $class.

> **class** *(string or array) (optional)* 
>   One or more classes to add to the class attribute, separated by a single space.

Use this parameter to make WordPress include the extra body classes you've added yourself.